# SNMP on Juniper SRX Chassis Cluster does not show node1

Tags: snmp, juniper-junos

I am trying to monitor an SRX (345) chassis cluster, via SNMP. The JUNOS documentation suggests that doing `snmpwalk` over `jnxContentsDescr` on the primary node should return details about all nodes. In my case, it does not.

`user@server:~# snmpwalk -v 2c -c 'XXXX' 172.18.1.145 jnxContentsDescr
JUNIPER-MIB::jnxContentsDescr.1.1.0.0 = STRING: node0 midplane
JUNIPER-MIB::jnxContentsDescr.2.1.0.0 = STRING: node0 PEM 0
JUNIPER-MIB::jnxContentsDescr.4.1.0.0 = STRING: node0 SRX340 Chassis fan 0
JUNIPER-MIB::jnxContentsDescr.7.1.0.0 = STRING: node0 FPC: FPC @ 0/*/*
JUNIPER-MIB::jnxContentsDescr.8.1.1.0 = STRING: node0 PIC: 8xGE,8xGE SFP Base PIC @ 0/0/*
JUNIPER-MIB::jnxContentsDescr.9.1.0.0 = STRING: node0 Routing Engine
JUNIPER-MIB::jnxContentsDescr.9.1.1.0 = STRING: node0 USB Hub`

I also seem to be missing metrics on things like node1 cpu usage and temperature.

Am I missing something here regarding how to monitor the second node of a cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having spent many weeks working with JTAC to find a solution... the answer was simply to reboot the node which is missing from the SNMP output.

I have set up a few SRX (345) clusters since having this issue and each time they have exhibited the fault. JTAC could not replicate so it's unlikely they will fix it.